# SuiteCRM - multiple Contact list for email

Tags: crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am completly new to suiteCRM and I created 2 modules holding contacts for different contact groups. So i have (together with the standart contacts list) 3 list. Now i want to be able to send on the easiest way emails to some persons (selectable) of all 3 lists (eg. to send inventations for events). The problem is i dont know how to set relations to be able to select all contacts, i am always just seeing the standart contacs list. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

And at this point is it possible to add a select list to the create and edit form to select a target group while creating a new contact?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not able to undertstand your problem.. Please specify what you have tried..

Comment: Hi thanks for trying to help me :) 

1) i was going to the:
Modules Builder -> new Package -> giving it a Name and a Key -> save
2) after that i clicked on this new package:
package -> New Module -> type in name  + label -> type = person -> save
3) repeated this one more time with the only difference type = company 
4) edited inside of the new moules the Fields, Labels and Layouts.
5) import data to these 2 lists
6) going to target lists
7) created a new target list
8) inside of the target list i clicked inside the contacts field the "select" button

Comment: 9) get a list of all contact in the default "Contacts" list only
10) going back to modules setup inside of the new persons list module:
"view relationships" -> add relationship -> Related Module: contacts, type Many to many and subpanel from Project Templates "default"

i always deployed it correctly but i was never able to get access to the contacts of my new module insite of the selection for target lists :/